# Generation of stubs in Microsoft IDL

Tags: client-server, rpc, idl

Providing interface in Microsoft IDL

```
[
    uuid(04802821-F237-486D-BC90-B6BB048DC8B2),
    version(1.0)
]
interface RPC
{
    void foo([in, string] char * string)
}
```

Generated stub and header files are rpc_c.c, rpc_s.c and rpc_h.h. In header file rpc_h.h declares function foo

```
void foo( char * string );
```

In rpc_c.c automatically defines the client version

```
void foo( char * string)
{
    NdrClientCall(...);
}
```

But now I want to implement client and server in the same program for testing purpose, which should appear

```
#include "rpc_h.h"
#include "rpc_c.c"
#include "rpc_s.c"

/*server foo*/

void foo(char * string)
{
    printf("%s\n", string);
}

/*server*/

void server()
{
    //RpcServerRegisterIfEx(...);
    //RpcServerUseProtseqEp(...);
    //RpcServerListen(...);
}

int main(int args, char * argv[])
{
    /*server runs*/

    CreateThread(NULL, 0, server, argv[1], 0, NULL);

    /*make RPC as client*/

    foo(argv[2]);
}
```

As you can see, there is certainly an error about re-definition of both client and server foo. So I can't but manually rename client foo in rpc_c.c to be

```
void foo_client( char * string)
{
    NdrClientCall(...);
}
```

and declare it along with server version in rpc_h.h

```
void foo_client( char * string );
void foo( char * string );
```

Therefore when I make RPC as client in main, I do

```
foo_client(argv[2]);
```

It works around but looks a bit hacky. Is there a decent solution to this instead?

**PS: For those who might concern, I develop with pure system RPC. It's not about COM, COM+, DCOM or even object-orientation at all. I'm developing a peer-to-peer application based on DHT, so I must implement client and server in the same application. Sorry about the com and dcom tags, they are now removed**

Comment: Hard to guess how you ended up with code like this, you should be generating code-less proxies these days, /Oicf midl option.  Post the midl.exe command line.

Comment: @HansPassant 
`/W1 /nologo /char signed /env win32 /h "%(Filename).h" /tlb "Release\BROKERNET.tlb"`
Actually what I have to do here is not about COM at all but purely RPC.

Answer (score 0):

Don't create the client and server in the same application.

Create a dummy client application on the same machine.  Your just making your life difficult.

Comment: No. I have to make client and server in the same application because it's peer-to-peer application I'm developing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question. The solution is to add separate prefixes to the client and server stubs using the midl /prefix switch. For example: `midl /prefix client "c_" server "s_"`

See [midl /prefix switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/midl/-prefix).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Tyler2P, updated to include essential parts of the answer.